# My website URL is weird in Google Search results

Tags: url, google-search

I am new to SEO, I have generated sitemap for my website and kept robots file. When we searched my website in Google, it is showing different URLs with my domain name.

For example, my site URL is `http://www.example.com/fr/home`.

But in Google Search results it is showing: `http://www.example.com/1C1lCqlPE6vtJKzq6aLBGntnVT5kk9jkKZ/M=`.

I am not understanding how this URL is generated.

Comment: I doubt this is because of sharethis/Addthis widget, check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84463/weird-data-appending-to-all-urls/84465#84465 , it happened to me but only in the website, not in Google result. check whether it is because of this widgets.

Comment: Is the search result URL in your question the complete URL or a [rewritten one like this Firefox extension fixes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-link-fix/)? Also, the second URL should return a 404 not found error then, correct?

Comment: @TomBrossman, yes the URL I mentioned is Search Result URL. And if we invoke second URL then website returning 404 page not found.

Comment: Are you using a CMS?

Comment: @w3d, My web application is e-commerce site based on Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Does the URL show up in Google Webmaster Tools Crawl Errors page (it should, if it's returning 404). If it does, you could check there to see if it indicates where the bad URL is linked-to from, and inspect that page to see if it's actually generating that URL on a page somewhere.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht, Thank you. Checked in Webmaster Tools Crawl Errors page where these URLS generating. as per Webmaster tools "Linked from",These URLs generated from my old website URLs. We have two websites OLD and new running.OLD website didn't had sitemaps and robots files and we are redirecting few of URLs from OLD website to new website. But when we searched in Google with old website URLs there are many URLS are weird like I mentioned above. As you said I inspected the pages but no clue in the page,Is there any problem if alt attribute has any numbers in img tag which I observed?

Comment: #s in an alt attribute shouldn't matter. It's not optimal obviously, but it shouldn't generate broken links. Are you saying that the pages that GWT says are linking to these broken URLs don't actually have the links in the HTML when you view them? Also, I'm not sure how it can show up in Google search results when it's returning a 404. Have you checked to make sure the server is ACTUALLY returning a 404, and not just saying that it is?

Comment: It's going to be pretty much impossible to help without the real URLs.

Comment: Please provide more information (such as the real URLs) so that this can be investigated further.

Answer (score 2):

You must have had the URL `http://www.example.com/1C1lCqlPE6vtJKzq6aLBGntnVT5kk9jkKZ/M=` at one time in the past.  This URL got indexed in Google's system, and now you just have to wait until your site is re-indexed and the results will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't generate any URLs for any website for search results. Maybe while developing an dynamic website, your link got generated and it got indexed in Google Search.  You can disable this link, if you have Google Webmasters account.